# What is the hashtag for Travel.se related tweets?

Tags: discussion, support

It would be interesting to see how travel.se, its questions and its answers are discussed on twitter. Is there a hashtag we could use to tweet and monitor?

Comment: If a fellow diamond comes along because of the 'support' tag, take a loot at http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/384/what-is-the-hashtag-for-travel-se-related-tweets/426#426

Answer (score 3):

The official Twitter handle for Travel.SE is [@StackTravel](http://twitter.com/#!/stacktravel), which is a firehose of automatically tweeted links to new questions. It tags questions with 'leading' tag, which sounds like a useful standard for tagging.

Comment: btw, that's the user account, not the hashtag

Answer (score 3):

We could use #TravelSE for now? It's short, and identifies that it's an abbreviation if we case it correctly.  Only possible conflict is that there's an actual website out there called http://travel.se! ;) Haven't seen them tweeting though.

Answer (score 1):

Does anybody know how to set up something on Twitter's competitors?

Google Plus has tweet-like things you can "follow".

I have some geek friends who are active on g+ and like to travel.

Facebook, trying to head Google off at the pass also added support for "following" things.

Most of us have a boatload of non geek friends here and I bet it's easier to get them to "follow" us than to sign up. After following us for a while I'm sure they are more likely to sign up.

Also Diaspora has now started up!

Anybody already know how these things work? Could you give the rest of us a bit of explanation?

Anybody interested enough to investigate how they work then give us the run down?

I know a high percentage of us are programmers as well as travellers and I for one should have plenty of hacking time over the next few months.

Comment: Do we need approval from our Stack Exchange overlords to start a Facebook page?

Comment: Very good question @AnkurBanerjee! Would adding the support or feature request tag to this question get an overlord to see it?